# Is it normal that a subdomain's CNAME record is suffixed with my domain?

Tags: cname, github-pages

I am using the [Alternc](http://alternc.org) control panel for shared hosting.

I am setting up a subdomain to point to github pages, as [described here](https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working/).

I need to point the CNAME record for my subdomain to .github.io, which I did with the alternc interface as seen in this image.

[image: adding cname record in alternc]

After waiting more than 24 hours, I got this message from github:

```
CNAME record should point to `your-username.github.io`, but it does not.
```

In effect, when visiting http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=cname%3asommet.terredesjeunes.org&run=toolpage#, the CNAME record seems to be set to:

```
alberto56.github.io.terredesjeunes.org
```

not

```
alberto56.github.io
```

Same thing when running `dig`:

```
$ dig sommet.terredesjeunes.org +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
...
;sommet.terredesjeunes.org. IN  A
sommet.terredesjeunes.org. 86400 IN CNAME   alberto56.github.io.terredesjeunes.org.
```

I would be expecting to see the CNAME being alberto56.github.io, not alberto56.github.io.terredesjeunes.org. Is this a glitch with alternc, or am I not understanding something?

Thanks!

Albert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full DNS names need to end in a `.`, the root zone, otherwise the current zone is appended to the name. So, you want to set your CNAME to `alberto56.github.io.` with the terminal period to indicate that resolution should start from the root zone.